# NSDictionary use object in text label and key in detailtextlabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    [super viewDidLoad]    
    { FloorList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Floor One", @"Floor Two", @"Floor Three", nil];
        FloorListAvailable = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"10 Available", @"2 Available", @"0 Available", nil]; 
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:FloorListAvailable forKeys:FloorList];
      }  
       }

   ...cellForRowAtIndexPath:..... 
        cell.textLabel.text = [@"%", FloorList];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text= [@"%", [dict objectForKey:FloorListAvailable]];
```

I have no clue what im doing right now. I just want a table view to show Floor 1 and in detailtextlabel to show the number available. I cant get that or understand how to get to that point. Thanks!

edit- I already have the table view made in storyboard and created a viewcontroller h and m file and this is being written in the FloorTableViewController.m file

Comment: You haven't explained anything, put more effort when making questions. We don't know in which method you are doing this, and how you created the table view. Edit the question to include these details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

in your tebleView Delegate "cellForRowAtIndex"  write this:

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",[FloorList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",[FloorListAvailable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

each time when cell is created it loads the object from array corresponding to the array values

Hope this will helps u

Comment: Those objects are already strings; they don't need to be formatted. You've also misspelled the method name.

Comment: Yess u r right. I just given an Idea. no problem how anyone can use this. anyway thanx for ur reply

Comment: Okay, but the idea you're giving is not a good one.

Comment: thanks in advance if u have better idea from this. can u share with me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried what you said but I am getting an error where I created the array. BTW I created the array in the view didload. I get the error "Called object type 'NSString *' is not a function or function pointer"

Comment: First alloc and init both array in viewDidLoad and release them in dealloc.  then use those array.
because wihtout alloc & init, the object has retain count 0 and it was released in autorelease pool that was running in background continously.